# Escribir archivo texto de pdf linea a linea

Tags: c#, archivo, itextsharp

necesito extraer texto de archivos pdf (linea a linea) pero no me escribe en el archivo texto;

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"c:\temp\textoPDF.pdf");
        int intPageNum = reader.NumberOfPages;
        string[] words;
        string line;
        string text;

        for (int i = 1; i <= intPageNum; i++)
        {
            text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());

            words = text.Split('\n');

                for (int j = 0, len = words.Length; j < len; j++)
                {
                    line = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(words[j]));
                    File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\", line);
                }

        }
    }
}
```

me sale error en File.WriteAllText No se puede encontrar una parte de la ruta de acceso 'c:\temp\'.'
porque sale el error?

Comment: Podrias decirnos que erro te sale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que definir el nombre de un archivo

```
File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\archivo.txt", line);
```

veras que indico el `archivo.txt` en la ruta

Ademas el `WriteAllText()` se supone se utiliza cuando tienes todos el texto completo, no dentro de un `for`

Sino deberias usar algo como esto

```
List<string> lineas = new List<string>();

for (int i = 1; i <= intPageNum; i++)
{
    text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());

    words = text.Split('\n');

    for (int j = 0, len = words.Length; j < len; j++)
    {
        string line = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(words[j]));
        lineas.Add(line);
    }

}

File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\temp\archivo.txt", lineas);
```

Comment: foreach (string linea in lineas)
                {
                    File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\temp\archivo.txt", lineas);
                } hay que ponerlo en un foreach

Comment: no, por eso "lineas" es un List<string>, este ira acumulando todas las lineas para depsues escribirlas todas juntas al final